# Why doesn't the G-test's Chi-squared "threshold" scale with sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

In the popular likelihood ratio test of goodness-of-fit (also known as the G-test: see, e.g., [here](http://www.biostathandbook.com/gtestgof.html)), the test statistic is calculated as

$$G(\mathbf{O},\mathbf{E})=2\sum_{i=1}^{M}O_{i}\log\frac{O_{i}}{E_{i}} \tag{1}$$

where $\sum_{i=1}^{M}O_{i}=N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{M}E_{i}=N$ are histogram counts of $N$ samples. I am interested in how the strength of the test scales with ensemble size. My first observation is that the sample size in the log fraction cancels out, but it affects the overall test statistic through the leading $O_{i}$ within the sum, so the statistic should scale linearly with the ensemble size $N$.

Now the p-value of the G-test is apparently calculated via the $\chi^2$ distribution, where the "threshold" statistic for a given significance level $\alpha$ is calculated as $ F^{-1} (q=1-\alpha;\text{dof}=M-1) $, where $F^{-1}$ is the inverse cdf of a chi-square distribution with $\text{dof}=M-1$ degrees of freedom.

Is this correct? It concerns me a bit is that this $\chi^2$ threshold value does not depend on the sample size $N$. If so, do you have some intuition or explanation for why? Is it because the G-test statistic itself (Eq. 1) scales with $N$?

Comment: Ever notice that Z test critical values don't scale with sample size... yet sample size still matters in a z test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should it? For instance, the critical value for a z-test (t-test but with known variance) does not depend on the sample size.

The test statistic will be influenced by the sample size, and that’s where you can get improved power by increasing the sample size. I suppose an alternative construction could be one where the test statistic does not depend on sample size but the critical value does, sure, but that is not what happens with the G-test (or any other test that comes to mind).

If neither the critical value nor the test statistic were influenced by the sample size, that would be concerning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Hmm, so is this a useful way of thinking about it? The $\chi^2$ distribution is the distribution of the test statistic for $N \rightarrow \infty$ under the null hypothesis $\mathbf{E}$. We can derive a threshold from that. Increasing $N$ has (presumably) two consequences for the G-test: the test metric goes up linearly, and its variance drops. If the null hypothesis is true, the test becomes more reliable primarily because the variance drops. If it is false, the test becomes more reliable mainly because the G-statistic scales away?

Comment: @J.Galt I have struggled for days to make sense of that. Could you please explain in a different way? For instance, what is the test metric, and what variance drops? // It might help you to think about a simpler test like the z-test (t-test but with a known variance) where the power calculations are fairly straightforward.